# Django Rest Framework API How to extract access_token from request?

Tags: django, oauth

My API is currently protected by the OAuth2TokenAuthentication from django-oauth-toolkit, so that it can validate API requests that contains access token in following ways:

1. as query param`?access_token=xxxx`
2. in header `Authorization: Bearer xxxx`

while I can hardcode in my API view to try to get the access token from those 2 places, is there a canonical way to obtain the token?

Answer (score 0):

I dug through the code inside OAuth2TokenAuthentication, and borrowed it into my API View:

```
class IntrospectView(APIView):
    """
    An API view that introspect a given token
    """
    serializer_class = TokenIntrospectSerializer
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        oauthlib_core = get_oauthlib_core()
        valid, r = oauthlib_core.verify_request(request, scopes=[])
        if not valid:
            raise APIException('Invalid token')
        return Response(TokenIntrospectSerializer(r.access_token).data)
```